# Get the word under the cursor what is my mistake?

Tags: c#, textbox, mouseevent, mouseover, getchar

What is my mistake ? I want to make a word on website to textbox2.And sorry because of my bad eng. :)

```
private void txtHoverWord_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if (!(sender is TextBox)) return;
    var targetTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (targetTextBox.TextLength < 1) return;

    var currentTextIndex = textBox2.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
    var wordRegex = new Regex(@"(\w+)");
    var words = wordRegex.Matches(textBox2.Text);
    if (words.Count < 1) return;

    var currentWord = string.Empty;
    for (var i = words.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (words[i].Index <= currentTextIndex)
        {
            currentWord = words[i].Value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (currentWord == string.Empty) return;
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox2, currentWord);
}
```

Comment: You getting any error, any exception? _What is my mistake?_ is not a good way to ask..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have inadvertently specified `textBox2` instead of `targetTextBox` in your code.

Try modifying it to the following:

```
private void txtHoverWord_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is TextBox)) return;
    var targetTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (targetTextBox.TextLength < 1) return;

    var currentTextIndex = targetTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
    var wordRegex = new Regex(@"(\w+)");
    var words = wordRegex.Matches(targetTextBox.Text);
    if (words.Count < 1) return;

    var currentWord = string.Empty;
    for (var i = words.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (words[i].Index <= currentTextIndex)
        {
            currentWord = words[i].Value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (currentWord == string.Empty) return;
    tooltip1.SetToolTip(targetTextBox, currentWord);
}
```

Noting that I changed `textBox2` to `targetTextBox` wherever it appeared in your code.

Comment: targetTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location); dont allow visual studio targettextbox havent getchar fonc.

Comment: @kdr_81 I think you are saying that `targetTextBox` doesn't support the `GetCharIndexFromPosition` method.  However, from .Net 2.0 onwards this function has existed on the `TextBox` class.  Could you try and clarify what the problem is you are experiencing?

Comment: now support :) but dont work I have 2 question
tooltip1.SetToolTip(targetTextBox, currentWord); its tooltip1 or tooltip ? And how I call this metod :)

Comment: @kdr_81 It will be whatever your `ToolTip` object is named in your code.  You originally named it `toolTip1` in your code.

Comment: You need to create a `ToolTip` object and then call `SetToolTip`.

Comment: it is work but only get by textbox how I use it from website ?

Comment: @kdr_81 I think you should raise that as a separate question, as your original question has already been answered. Make sure your new question refers to a website and uses the `asp.net` tag.